# Changing the final layer in caffe

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

This is an extension of the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43750565/how-to-load-reference-caffemodel-for-training/43751716?noredirect=1#comment74546273_43751716) on how to add existing weights to the model before training.

I wanted to use existing weights but my final layer output 50 instead of 1000(since the network was trained to classify 1000 items). From the previous post, by changing the name of the output layer, I was able to add the weights. But then I realized there are other layers that are dependent on that final layer. Here is a snippet from VGG network:

```
 layer {
   name: "loss3/classifier"
   type: "InnerProduct"
   bottom: "pool5/7x7_s1"
   top: "loss3/classifier"
   param {
     lr_mult: 1
     decay_mult: 1
   }
   param {
     lr_mult: 2
     decay_mult: 0
   }
   inner_product_param {
     num_output: 50
     weight_filler {
       type: "xavier"
     }
     bias_filler {
       type: "constant"
       value: 0
     }
   }
 }
 layer {
   name: "loss3/loss3"
   type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
   bottom: "loss3/classifier"
   bottom: "label"
   top: "loss3/loss3"
   loss_weight: 1
 }
 layer {
   name: "loss3/top-1"
   type: "Accuracy"
   bottom: "loss3/classifier"
   bottom: "label"
   top: "loss3/top-1"
   include {
     phase: TEST
   }
 }
 layer {
   name: "loss3/top-5"
   type: "Accuracy"
   bottom: "loss3/classifier"
   bottom: "label"
   top: "loss3/top-5"
   include {
     phase: TEST
   }
   accuracy_param {
     top_k: 5
   }
 }
```

My questions are:

1. What exactly are bottom and top arguments?
2. Do I need to change the names of the "loss3/classifier" in the subsequent two layers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite a basic question. I strongly recommend that you go over some documentation and basic caffe tutorials to get the basics of caffe. [This tutorial](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/net_layer_blob.html) can be a good starting point.

---

A deep network has an underlying graph describing the "flow" of data from the inputs of the nets to the predicted outputs. The snippet you attached in your question describe one such graph.
Each layer represents a "processing unit" along the "data path": its inputs are the `"bottom"` blob(s) and the layer outputs its processed data as the `"top"` blobs.
So, if you have a layer

```
layer {
  name: "loss3/classifier"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "pool5/7x7_s1"
  top: "loss3/classifier"
  ...
}
```

The this layer performs an `"InnerProduct"` operation (defined by layers' `type`). It performs the operation on the input blob `"pool5/7x7_s1"` (defined as the `bottom`) and outputs the result to blob `"loss3/classifier"` (defined as the `top` blob). The learnable parameters of this layer (weights and bias) are stored and accessed by caffe using the layer's name `"loss3/classifier"`.
Therefore, if you change the layyer's *name* to `"loss3/classifier_50"` **without** changing the `top` you will get the desired effect: caffe will not copy he weights of this layer, but will keep the output of this layer connected to the other layers.

---

BTW,
Are you sure you are using VGG net? this prototxt looks like GoogLeNet architecture...
Note that AlexNet, VGG and GoogLeNet are three quite different nets.

Comment: Ah yes. You are right. It's googlenet. I apologize for such basic question. I will definitely go over the tutorial. Thank you!